# Search API and Facets API with multilingual taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search, i18n-l10n

I have some taxonomy terms and the settings look like this.

[image]

All these terms have been translated.

[image]

After indexing the content with Search API and Facets API, the facets are not shown with translation.

[image]

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

To localize FacetAPI you should install [FacetAPI i18n](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_i18n).

> The [Facet API Translation](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_i18n) module integrates the Facet API and
>   Internationalization projects allowing site builders to translate
>   configuration settings. This module also overrides common mapping
>   callbacks, such as the content type mapping callback, to translate the
>   display name of facets.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But i found out from these links thats you need to translate each taxonomy from translate interface. which is not a solution yet .
https://drupal.org/node/1210730#comment-4701718
https://drupal.org/node/1276812#comment-6727336
https://drupal.org/node/1340858

Comment: Just found out that if your taxonomy field is indexed as a "Term Taxonomy", it will expose a facet block which will show translated terms (no need for translate interface). in my case the block name was "Facet API: Search service: recepie index : cat"

Comment: btw "Facet API Translation" module is disabled .